# React router - не уничтожать компонент при переходе к другому компоненту

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-router, react-router-dom

Есть форма на react и еще пара страниц, если пользователь начинает заполнять форму, а потом перейдет на другую страницу, то у компонента формы вызывается событие `componentWillUnmount` и компонент стирается вместе со всеми заполнеными данными. По возвращению обратно на страницу с формой придется все заполнять заново. Собственно вопрос как предотвратить вызов `componentWillUnmount` или как не потерять уже введенные данные.

Для примера набросал небольшой пример [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel217/2x1psdqj/). Здесь если я начну вводить данные в поле в компоненте `Home`, а потом перейду на `About`, то по возвращению поле будет пустым

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.Router = window.ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter ;
    this.Link = window.ReactRouterDOM.Link;
    this.Route = window.ReactRouterDOM.Route;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
 <this.Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <this.Link to="/">Home</this.Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <this.Link to="/about">About</this.Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <this.Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <this.Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </div>
    </this.Router>
    )
  }
}

function Home() {
  return (
  <input type="text"/>
  );
}

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, то, что Вам нужно находится в компоненте `Home`:

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**app.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <NavLink exact to="/">
            Home
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**home.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

let foo = { name: "" };

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = foo;
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    foo = this.state;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.name} />
    );
  }
}
```

**about.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>Hello from about</h2>;
  }
}
```

*P.S. Ссылка на [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/13vp2wqpx4) (Тут удобнее посмотреть на результат);*

*P.S.S Код не по Вашему примеру, но суть одна.*

*P.S.S. Если требуется объяснение - напишите в комментариях, добавлю комментарии к коду*

Comment: Вся суть в том что во время вызова `componentWillUnmount` данные из поля сохраняются в переменной `let foo`, а в конструкторе возвращаются обратно?

Comment: @Dantessss, да, всё верно.